# Photon Polarization

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm having some issues to understand some concepts related with the polarization of photons, especifically the 'pratical' diference between a superposition of two polarizations (let's say $|H\rangle + |V\rangle$) and a single polarization ($|H\rangle$ or $|V\rangle$). I've read a topic similiar ([Can we determine whether a photon's polarization is fixed or in a superposition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377035/can-we-determine-whether-a-photons-polarization-is-fixed-or-in-a-superposition)), but this is not exactly what I'm trying to understand. My question: it's possible to create a experimental arrangement capable of making a diference between a superposition state or a single polarized state? Would it be diferent if I had a source who provides me with both $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$ in a known rate? That is: can we use a arrangement of polarizers, mirrors, beam spliters and detectores to find out wether a source is providing these states? My original idea is to use two ortogonal polarizers in 45 degrees but I'm having some issues to understand the principles behind the situation.

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way we can tell the difference between $|H\rangle$ and $|H\rangle+|V\rangle$? Can you explain a bit more why your question is not the same as the question in your link?

Comment: @enumaris, exactly! It seems to me that my question is not the same as the question in the link I've posted because I want to propose a arrangement to distinguish these diferent states(my original idea is to use two ortogonal polarizers in 45 degrees ) but I'm having some issues to understand the principles behind the situation.

Comment: You can use polarizers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer

Comment: @Avantgarde this is my original idea but I having some troubles to see the big picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is you will have to have multiple photons prepared identically, and make multiple polarization measurements (using a polarization filter) to be able to distinguish between $|H\rangle$ and $|H\rangle+|V\rangle$. One way I can do it would be to get a polarization filter and only allow vertically polarized light through. So I'm looking for the presence of a $|V\rangle$ state. If I make 10,000 measurements and I find no component $|V\rangle$ (all my results come back negative, i.e. no photons were let through the polarizer) then I am relatively certain the state was $|H\rangle$ to begin with and not $|H\rangle+|V\rangle$. If the original state was the latter, I would expect 50% of my measurements to come back positive. (If the original state was $|V\rangle$ then all 10,000 of my results should have come back positive). By building out these probabilities, I can figure out what state the photon was in originally.

This answers the question of "the photon was known to be in some pure state, how can I determine what that pure state *was*?". Interestingly though, when one *does* measure the vertical polarization, for photons which do pass through the polarizer, their state is now changed to be exactly $|V\rangle$. So say a photon starts in state $|H\rangle+|V\rangle$ and you measure $V$, then for photons that pass through your polarizer, their state is now $|V\rangle$ and NOT $|H\rangle+|V\rangle$. By measuring the state, you have changed the state (see the joke in Futurama about a "quantum finish" in a horse race). So, if one wants a bunch of $|V\rangle$ state photons, one can merely pass a bunch of randomly prepared photons through an (idealized) vertical polarizer and they will end up in that state. If one wants a bunch of $|H\rangle+|V\rangle$ photons, one can pass it through a (45$^\circ$) diagonally polarized filter to accomplish that.

Comment: the thing was so much easier than I thought!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I wonder how much diferent would be the experimental arrangement if I had a scenario where the source provides me with both |H⟩ and |V⟩(but not the two at the same time) in a known rate

Comment: @CaueEvangelista then as far as I can tell your question becomes identical to the one you linked and the answers there should provide you the answer.

Comment: If you measure 50%, how do you know the incoming photons were all $|H\rangle+|V\rangle$, but not an equal mix of $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$ from two different sources?

Comment: @safesphere right, so in my answer I explicitly did not address the issue of there being possibly different sources. As you can see, I answered starting with "multiple photons prepared identically". If you want to distringuish between $|H\rangle+|V\rangle$ and an inhomogenous mix of $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$ (essentially pure state vs non pure state) then you would have to look at intereference effects which are talked about in the OP's linked answer. I didn't want to reproduce that discussion here.